# VBA opening .csv but changing formats

Tags: excel, vba, csv, parsing

Is there a quick setting option to solve this annoying issue?
My VBA code edits a node of an .xml file according to the content a .csv file. The problem is that when I use the following line of code, the .csv is parsed into columns, but the formats are changed.
`set mywbook=Workbooks.Open("myfile.csv")`.
In particular, numeric text is formatted as number and decimal values in .csv, originally displayed as points, are converted into decimal with commas. I know this depends upon the default local Windows setting. I've tried to fix that bug by using something like `.Range("A:A").Text`or `Cstr(match.Offset(0,3).Value)` but it doesn't work as desired. I wanted to avoid something like `Replace(.Cells(28,4).Value, ",",".")`
Is there something like the `Workbooks.Open`command which allows me to keep .csv as it is, just parsed in columns?

Comment: Re "... fix that bug ..." this is not bug, this is the way how excel works. It would be bug, if after saving your changes into csv/xml back, points were converted to commas, making resulting file invalid. If you could provide some context, why you need preserve exact visual representation of values, then maybe we could offer some ideas. BTW, you likely can change Excel defaults about how to show numeric values, independently of WIndows regional settings.

Comment: I was having a similar issue where my table, when saved in csv format would remove leading zeroes off of a text string that was assumed to be a number. To fix it, I started using alpha-numeric serials instead of just numeric, now it understands not to remove leading zeroes.   I would suggest that you do similarly, and just alter your saved values so that they work inside the csv format.

Comment: You will have more success **IMPORT**ing `csv` files. Using either the legacy wizard or Power Query, you can then tell Excel how to parse the incoming data. That will be much simpler than trying to correct it after Excel has decided, on its own, how to parse the data.

Comment: Ok, could you give me some hints? What can I do instead of Workbooks.Open?